# Show that the composition of continuous functions is a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

I know this demonstration is a classic for analysis, metric spaces and general topology courses, but I would like to know if my reasoning is correct.

Let $f: X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g : Y \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ real functions that are continuous in the points a $\in$ X and $f(a) \in Y$. Given $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta_1 > 0$ such that

$$\forall y \in Y \cap [(f(a) - \delta_1, f(a) + \delta_1)], \quad \mid g(y) - g(f(a)) \mid < \varepsilon.$$

Because the continuity of $f$, given $\delta_1 > 0$, there exists $\delta_2 > 0$ such that

$$\forall x \in X \cap [a - \delta_2, a + \delta_2)], \quad \mid f(x) - f(a) \mid < \delta_1.$$

Let $\delta = min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$. Follow that

$$\forall x \in X \cap [a - \delta, a + \delta)], \quad \mid g(f(x)) - g(f(a)) \mid < \varepsilon.$$

Comment: It looks OK for metric spaces. For topological spaces, you don't have a metric, so the argument is different.

Answer (score 1):

In general topology, the proof would go as follows. Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ and $g : Y \rightarrow Z$ be two continuous map and $U \subset Z$ an open set. Then, $g^{-1}(U) \subset Y$ is open by continuity of $g$ and $(g \circ f)^{-1}(U) = f^{-1}(g^{-1}(U)) \subset X$ is open by continuity of $f$. In consequence, $g \circ f : X \rightarrow Z$ is a continuous map. Of course, in the case where the considered topological spaces possess a metric, then their topologies can be defined from it and the proof you gave can be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another proof that uses squential criteria.Let $f:X \to \Bbb{R}$ and $g:Y \to \Bbb{R}$ be continuous at $a$ and $f(a)$ respectively.Let $\{x_n\}$ be sequence that converges to $a$.Since $f$ is continuous at $a$,$\{f(x_n)\}$ converges to $f(a)$.And $g$ is continuous at $f(a)$ and $\{f(x_n)\}$ goes to $f(a)$,therefore $g(f(x_n))$ goes to $g(f(a))$,i.e. $(g o f)(x_n)$ goes to $(gof)(a)$.Hence $gof$ is continuous at $a$.